# UWP WebView AdBlocker

Tags: javascript, uwp, xmlhttprequest, adblock, javascript-injection

I am making UWP applications and I use WebView for displaying webpage content. The content is not mine so I would like to block the annoying video ads. I am using the function below to put css that hides banners. 
How to approach this task? Should I filter every HTTP request and if it meets some regex to stop the request? Or should I block the external javascripts that execute the ads? There are topics about this for Android WebView, but I couldn't make it work on UWP.

```
private async void InvokeScript()
{
    string functionString = "let link = document.createElement('link'); link.rel = 
    'stylesheet'; link.type = 'text/css'; link.href = 'ms-appx-web:///MyCss.css'; 

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);";

    await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great solution from the Microsoft forum. 
For UWP WebView FrameNavigationStarting does the job!

```
webView.FrameNavigationStarting += webView_FrameNavigationStarting;

private void webView_FrameNavigationStarting(object sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    // Cancel navigation if URL is not allowed. (Implemetation of IsAllowedUri not shown.)
    if (!IsAllowedUri(args.Uri))
        args.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ad in different website may be different, there are no general scenario to remove all the ads.

To remove the ad in the website, you need to get the website content and find the code of the ad , then you can inject js code to hide the advertisement.

Comment: That is good solution. I have found a way to hide the banners. How to hide video ads from Google? They are executed from scripts. How to block them?

Comment: Firstly, you should find the video ads' container, if they are iframe or div, you should be able to hind them.

Comment: I want to simulate an adblocker. AdBlockers have list of domains and somehow block the HTTP requests from them. Can JavaScript do that?

Comment: Can javascript do that? The answer is no, AdBlockers is a plug- in and use the browser's API, but the WebView doesn't have much functions as a browser.

Comment: Is there another option? Video ads trigger events on complete, canceled etc. When I stop all request with the prototype or hide the iframe the page stops working.

Comment: Javascript can not block http requests of other js scripts. And currently webview doesn't offer the ability to block js scripts , so there is no other options.